# CSS3 position animating not affecting siblings?

Tags: css, animation, css-position, transform

I'm wondering, if CSS position animations with "transition" and "transform" really don't affect the position of objects around the animated object, or if I'm missing something. I'm trying to get it to affect the sibling.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transform: translateY(10em);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2L7B/6/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't seems like it does. Is there any problem actually ?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what my goal is.

Comment: Ok... this is the expected behaviour. Use margins for this : http://jsfiddle.net/W2L7B/4/

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately animating the margin property results in a jumpy animation in Safari (not webkit in general).

Comment: One of the problems with animating `transform` is that the elements original space will remain as is. Which means it won't affect the surrounding elements. (But I guess you already figured this out)

Answer (score 0):

For `translate3d` you need to have `perspective` I believe. Try this:

```
.slide {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,10em,0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you got the OP goal.

Comment: I know but how is it supposed to work if the transition itself isn't doing anything. Was just point that out.

Comment: Thank you for your input but unfortunately it doesn't affect the animation. I changed the code to just 2d.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both of them to move, just add the transition to `#second` as well, then add this css:

```css
.slide, .slide + div { /* or use ~ if you want it to affect all next siblings */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10em);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W2L7B/7/)

Comment: Yeah, thought so too, but I wasn't sure if there's another possibility :)

Comment: There's not using transforms unless you wrap everything you want to move and add the class to that instead